# How to add line (manual min/max allowed value) to boxplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying out to visualize some measurement data in a boxplot using the: `boxplot(x,g)` command in MATLAB. There's a manual giving a minimum and maximum allowed value. How can I add this value to the boxplot like in the painted screenshot below?

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following (after you use `boxplot`):

```
max_bounds = [2 3 2]; % set the maximum bound by category
min_bounds = [-1 -2 -1]; % set the minimum bound by category
x = repmat(1:numel(max_bounds),[2 1]); % make x values for all categories
x = bsxfun(@plus,x,[-0.1; 0.1]); % make the lines in length of 0.2
hold on
% plot it all:
plot(x,repmat(min_bounds,[2 1]),'r',x,repmat(max_bounds,[2 1]),'r')
```

[image: boxplot]